# PHP: Echo menu from three dimensional array using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I've got this multidimensional array to display a menu that my website uses in some PHP code. I've been doing some experimenting and reading and I want to get this to work with a multidimensional array so that I can dynamically display the corresponding menu.

I have 3 different menus that can be displayed, "one", "two", and "three".

```
$pages = array(
        'one' => array(
            'about 1' => array('services 1', 'partners 1'), 
            'events 1', 
            'contact 1'
        ), 
        'two' => array(
            'about 2' => array('services 2', 'partners 2'), 
            'events 2', 
            'contact 2'
        ), 
        'three' => array(
            'about 3' => array('services 3', 'partners 3'), 
            'events 3', 
            'contact 3'
        )
    );
```

I have tried a few things so far, and I can't figure this out - I think my multidimensional array needs to be changed around?

Basically if `$current_page == 'one'` then I want to echo the corresponding array for `'one'`.

It would have to be something like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<ul class="menu">';
    if ($current_page == 'one'){
        foreach($pages['one'] as $page => $dropdown){
            if (array has third dimension){ // pseudo code if pages have third dimension
                echo '<li class="has-dropdown">' $page '</li>\n';
                echo '<ul class="dropdown">';
                foreach($pages['one'] as $page => $dropdown){
                    echo '<li>' . $dropdown . '</li>\n';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            } else { // no third dimension
                foreach($pages['one'] as $page){
                    echo '<li>' $page '</li>\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    elseif ($current_page == 'two'){
        foreach($pages['two'] as $page){
            if (array has third dimension){ // pseudo code if pages have third dimension
                echo '<li class="has-dropdown">' $page '</li>\n';
                echo '<ul class="dropdown">';
                foreach($pages['one'] as $page => $dropdown){
                    echo '<li>' . $dropdown . '</li>\n';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            } else { // no third dimension
                foreach($pages['one'] as $page){
                    echo '<li>' $page '</li>\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    elseif ($current_page == 'three'){
        foreach($pages['three'] as $page){
            if (array has third dimension){ // pseudo code if pages have third dimension
                echo '<li class="has-dropdown">' $page '</li>\n';
                echo '<ul class="dropdown">';
                foreach($pages['one'] as $page => $dropdown){
                    echo '<li>' . $dropdown . '</li>\n';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            } else { // no third dimension
                foreach($pages['one'] as $page){
                    echo '<li>' $page '</li>\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

The above doesn't work, it's just a rough picture of what I've been trying. The question is really: how do I use a foreach loop to display my menu? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what to say, it's just code. Study it and ask if you have any questions, I'll be glad to help!

Note that this code will only handle 3 dimensional arrays, if you need to add more sub-levels it's a good idea to look into recursion but it *may* be a more complicated topic.

```
$pages = array(
    'one' => array(
        'about 1' => array('services 1', 'partners 1'),
        'events 1',
        'contact 1'
    ),
    'two' => array(
        'about 2' => array('services 2', 'partners 2'),
        'events 2',
        'contact 2'
    ),
    'three' => array(
        'about 3' => array('services 3', 'partners 3'),
        'events 3',
        'contact 3'
    )
);

$current_page = 'one';

echo '<ul class="menu">';
if (array_key_exists($current_page, $pages)) {
    foreach($pages[$current_page] as $item => $items) {
        echo '<li class="has-dropdown">';


        if (is_array($items)) {
            echo $item . '<ul class="dropdown">';
            foreach($items as $page => $dropdown) {
                echo '<li>'.$dropdown.
                '</li>\n';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }else{
            echo $items;
        }

        echo '</li>';
    }
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tested it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed7e84d13f0fd2ffecf155a16e1865d19659cdf9 and played around with it a little, you're awesome! I don't have any questions atm though, but I will definitely look into recursion

Comment: I do have a question for you now! Is it possible to put that into a function and then call the function like this... `$navigation = myMenuFunction(); echo $navigation;` ?

Comment: @Matthew well of course. You'll need to consider the scope of the function. Store the html in a variable instead of `echo` and then return that variable from the function.